# Как обратиться к свойству объекта внутри функции, если свойством объекта должен быть принимаемый параметр?

Tags: javascript, параметры

Нужно что то типа такого, но только что бы работало.

```
let func = (array, param) => {
    if(array[0]. + param) {
        console.log('Ура! Работает!');
    }
}

func(F, 'age')
```

Из кода выше понятно, что нужно получить свойство age нулевого объекта в массиве. Не пойму как после точки добавить параметр

```
 if(array[0]. + param)
```

Comment: array[0][param] без точки

Comment: Т.е. нужно проверить существует ли `array[0].age`

Comment: Супер! Всё заработало!